# Failure to play video in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, video-streaming, odoo

I am trying to make a "home made streaming system" which is composed of a Postgresql database, `Odoo11(Python3.8)` and `Flutter(Dart)`.

The idea is to create an endpoint in `Odoo` through which I get the URL of the video associated with the database: [Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZ8Ev.png)

The important thing is "mainvideo" which contains information of a `mp4` file in hexadecimal format. It is the content of the answer. The generated URL look like [this](http://localhost:8069/downloadVideoFile2/56/6).

Now when I attack the endpoint from Postman I get a response without any problem :
[Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J13Nu.png)

The problem appears when I try to play the video from flutter (With a virtualized mobile):
[Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyjyX.png)

I get this error : [Error Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9q3SS.png)

Also say that when they are small videos do not fail, only with longer videos and also when I click repeatedly on try it works.

I don't know if anyone has encountered this problem or knows how to solve it. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: it seems your specified video `url` is not correct

Comment: Then, why Postman shows the video?  Another thing to note is that sometimes I get the following error: "Loading finished before preparation is complete"

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help, After all, I solved that problem. The problem was when playing it from an emulator, when I tried it from a physical device I had no problem. I hope this may help others.